# Injected database context fails to connect at high load

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, autofac

I am using AutoFac for dependency injector in web api project.
I am resolving dependency like below...

```
builder.RegisterType<DbContext>().InstancePerRequest().WithParameter("nameOrConnectionString", "name=TestDbContext");
        builder.RegisterType<TestDbContext>().InstancePerRequest();
        builder.RegisterType<TestDbContext>().As<ITestDbContext>().InstancePerRequest();
        builder.RegisterType<TestDbRepository>().As<ITestDbRepository>().InstancePerRequest();
```

It is working fine when hit a single api route. But when our QA team doing performance testing with jMeter which hitting multiple request at a time, some of requests get fail and get db related error, like below errors...

```
 The underlying provider failed on Open.
System.InvalidOperationException: The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is connecting.
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosedConnecting.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext](TTarget target, Action`2 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.Open(DbConnection connection, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.<>c__DisplayClass1.<Execute>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open()
```

But this error is not consistent some times it get passed but some times this error comes.
Please help me if any thing we need to modify with Autofac dependency resolver.

Comment: Are you sure that the error is due to your Autofac implementation?

Comment: Not sure exactly, but error looks like multi threading request error, as when I hit it normally single request at a time, it works  fine, only when it hits multiple request at a time, it is throwing error. Resolve scope I am using InstancePerRequest for DBContext, that's why I am getting doubt on that.
I am using entity framework for db connection.

Comment: Which of your database contexts are failing? Why is TestDbContext registered twice? (Use AsSelf() and register in one line.)

Comment: @TravisIllig TestDbContext is registered twice because once it register itself and in second it register Interface ITestDbContext .

Comment: If you resolve it both ways in one request you'll get two different instances of the context. Use AsSelf on the line with the interface and remove the duplicate.